# In Java, how do you use the Log.e (or any function) to list all variables used in a code

Tags: java

Just started learning Java and during the tutorial, it appears there is a Log.e command run by the tutor and it displays all the variables used in the code without typing individually. Anyone know how I can replicate this?

Below is my code so far.

```
        // Increase the score after alien is shot
    playerScore = playerScore + 10;

    // Add a bonus to the score based on bonusMultiplier and levelNumber
    int bonusMultiplier = 5;
    int levelNumber = 23;
    playerScore += bonusMultiplier * levelNumber;

    // Append more text to the string
    playerName += "- Breakout inventor";

    // Increase the value of the variable by 1
    horizontalLocationOnScreen ++;

    // How many seconds since 1970
    long secondsSince1970 = millisecondsSince1970 / 1000;

    // Make playing the opposite of whatever it currently is
    playing = !playing;

    // Output the value of all the variables
    Log.e("playerScore =", "" + playerScore);
```

Comment: You should probably add the Android tag, because Log is an Android-specific class. Also, it only outputs what it is told to. In this case, it is outputting the value of the playerScore variable in a human-readable way.

Answer (score 0):

You might be doing android development.

You can replicate it very easily.

So Log is android class used for writing logs.
Below link can help you understand further about Log class

[Understanding Android Log API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#e(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

Now Log.e() method is specifically used for sending error message.

It should be good if you define first tag so for example

```
private static final String TAG = "PlayerScore =";
```

Then you can call your Log.e() method

```
Log.e(TAG, "" + playerScore);
```